# Creating a record in related tables simultaneously in access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have my main table: `tbl1Order_Model` and 2 related tables `tbl2Order_Pairs` and `tbl2Order_Customer`.

I have a form in datasheet view and fields `Pairs` and 'Customer' are "hyperlinked" (not a real hyperlink, simply an `On GotFocus` event that fires up and opens those related forms.

So when my user is filling up the new record in the main form and tabs to next field and that field happens to be `Pairs` a new modal/popup form opens up to specify the exact details of pairs (sizes etc). These then add up and on main form only the `Total` number is shown.

I use `DSUM` function to find out this total - `DSum("[35]+[36]+[37]+[38]+[39]+[40]+[41]+[42]+[43]+[44]+[45]+[46]", "tbl2Order_Pairs", "Order_ID = " & Order_ID)`.

And similarly for the `Customer` details - a more in-depth form shows up to fill in the customer details and specifications.

This works perfectly for old records (ie. when I want to change the already existing data). However, when I want to create a NEW record, I cannot create it (yet) in the sub-tables as the record doesn't exist in the main table yet. The realtionship is one-to-one, referential integrity, update and delete on change.

I would like to keep this (so that when the record is deleted from `tbl1OrdeR_Model` it is also deleted from related tables).

Any way to accomplish this?

Comment: You can just add some code just prior to the opening of "Pairs" form to check for the presence of the record in the 'Model' table, and if not found, then save it. Depending on your design, if you have a 'Cancel' button, then you would need to  remove any unwanted record (or prompt asking if they want to discard).

Comment: I do have that, basically before I open the form I do "CurrentDb.Execute INSERT..." but the problem is that the record is not yet created in the main table and as it is 1-1 relationship, it cannot be added to the sub-tables YET.

Comment: Assuming your form uses bound controls, then do what @ypicot suggested. Using the '.Execute' statement doesn't 'talk' to the form, thus the form still will have the Dirty flag set.

Answer (score 0):

To flush the data from the form to the table, do a Me.Dirty = False

Something like :

```
Sub txtMyControl_OnFocus()
    Me.Dirty = False
    DoCmd.FormOpen "mysubform"
End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly does `Me.Dirty = False` achieves here?

Comment: It flush your data from the form to the table.
So your pop-up can use updated data from the table.